# Understanding meaning of 0 ? 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have come to a point where I need to create a script on my new employer.

The problem is, one part of algorithm that I need to script is directly calculated inside the visual studio.

The line is

```
decimal averageCaseSize = totalPolicy == 0 ? 0 : (totalPremium / totalPolicy);
```

Does anyone know what is the meaning of `== 0 ? 0 :`

Hope I am asking on the right site.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Many luck for You and new employer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a ternary operator, this could be accomplished with the following.

```
decimal averageCaseSize = totalPolicy == 0 ? 0 : (totalPremium / totalPolicy);
```

In long form it looks like this-

```
if(totalPolicy == 0)
    decimal averageCaseSize = 0
else
    decimal averageCaseSize = (totalPremium / totalPolicy);
```